# How to launch firefox (not firefox-bin) using Selenium 3.4.3,

Tags: python, macos, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I want to launch firefox process(not firefox-bin) using selenium 3.4.3 on mac OSX 10.12.2 . I have GeckoDriver version 0.18.0 and firefox version as 55.0

By default, it launches firefox-bin through selenium. I want to change the process as 'firefox' instead to 'firefox-bin'. I tried changing the path in firefox_binary.py in selenium folder of site_packages. But it did not work, it still launched firefox-bin.

Python version is 2.7

Answer (score 0):

Specify the firefox executable when build driver.

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

// replace the path to path of your firefox process, please use absolute path
// and make your account has the execution right on the firefox process
binary = FirefoxBinary('F:\FirefoxPortable\Firefox.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
```